# Azure-hosted ASP.NET Web API cannot access appsettings.json

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, file, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to publish my .NET 7 Web API on Azure as App Service + Database.
Locally I execute the following code to get appsettings.json working in my dotnet publish (-ed) app:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Configuration
    .SetBasePath(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "src", "Web"))
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{builder.Environment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
    .Build();
```

For some reason otherwise it only works in IDE and won't work in dotnet publish'ed app.

But on the Azure I get:

```
Unhandled exception. System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: /home/site/wwwroot/src/Web/
2023-04-13T12:29:00.959798795Z    at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(String root, ExclusionFilters filters)
2023-04-13T12:29:00.959811695Z    at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationExtensions.SetBasePath(IConfigurationBuilder builder, String basePath)
2023-04-13T12:29:00.966010289Z    at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in /home/runner/work/flitch-backend/flitch-backend/src/Web/Program.cs:line 14
2023-04-13T12:29:04.369525714Z /opt/startup/startup.sh: line 17:    69 Aborted                 (core dumped) dotnet Web.dll
```

I think the problem might be in the folder structure, my folder structure is like that:

Application
Application/src
Application/src/Web (the project I run and the directory where appsettings.json reside)

Here's the github repo of the project I try to publish: https://github.com/Rostand-Corp/flitch-backend/tree/develop

appsettings.json properties are:
Build action: Content
Copy to output directory: Copy always

I have tried changing changing path to just current directory, but it won't work

Comment: I have a feeling that this is the right solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39157781/the-configuration-file-appsettings-json-was-not-found-and-is-not-optional/52461586#52461586

Comment: If the other answer you point to is absolutely correct I would close this question as duplicate

Comment: I have tried the answer you provided the link for, but it didn't help (well, it is a good practice anyway, I guess)
You may close the question, I guess, but I'd leave it. It may be useful since the one I have provided is not related to Azure and I suspected only Azure's file system to cause the problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Published .Net Core 2 application does not read appsettings.json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50578013/published-net-core-2-application-does-not-read-appsettings-json-file)

Comment: @MaythamFahmi yes

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the solution [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50578013)

I was running `dotnet Web.dll` from my source code directory and therefore
`Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` was been evaluating to the source code directory.

Using this helped:

```bash
cd *myPublishedAppDirectory*
dotnet Web.dll
```

Instead of this:

```bash
dotnet *myPublishedAppDirectory*/Web.dll
```

`Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` is now evaluated correctly.